# Is possible using Regular Expressions within PL/SQL function?

Tags: regex, oracle, function, plsql

I'm coding a simple PL/SQL to format employees CUIL (Social Security ID) The problem is I want to replace one o more '-' or '/' or spaces for a simple '-' and my code works fine for spaces and '/' but I don't have lucky for the other one. Can you help me? Thanks

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION formatear_cuit_cuil(p_cuit_cuil VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    v_length VARCHAR2(50) := p_cuit_cuil;
BEGIN
    IF
        LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(v_length, '[/ | |.]+')) <> 11 THEN
            RETURN 'El CUIT/CUIL no tiene el largo correcto';
    END IF;

    IF 
        REGEXP_LIKE(
            p_cuit_cuil, 
            '^[0-9][0-9][ /-]+[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][ /-]+[0-9]$'
        ) THEN
            RETURN REGEXP_REPLACE(p_cuit_cuil, '/+| +', '-');
    ELSE
        RETURN 'CUIT/CUIL no tiene el formato correcto';
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN 'Error al formatear CUIT/CUIL';
END formatear_cuit_cuil;
```

Example that works
[image: Works Fine!]

Example that does not work
[image: Doesn't work]

Comment: I'm not an expert, but wouldn't you want `-+` as part of your `replace` call? `RETURN REGEXP_REPLACE(p_cuit_cuil, '/+| +|-+', '-');`

Comment: I can't vote your comment. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as a regexp_replace - `'([ /-]+)', '-'`

e.g.

```
select regexp_replace('///  98   //////   46134679    1', '([ /-]+)', '-')
  from dual
```

returns `-98-46134679-1`

This matches one or more of the specified characters and replaces them with a single `-`

Comment: Yes. Your answer is correct. Thanks for your help. I've edited my code and now It works fine! Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started:

```
with a as  (
   select '98  46134679////1' as before from dual
union all
   select '98 ////// 46134679  1' as before from dual
) 
select a.before, 
       regexp_replace(a.before, 
       '^([0-9][0-9])([ /-])+([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])([ /-]+)([0-9])$', 
       '\1-\3-\5') as formatted from a;
```

Which produces this:

```
BEFORE                      FORMATTED
98     46134679////  1      98-46134679-1
98 ////// 46134679  1       98-46134679-1
```

I basically use sets of parentheses around parts of the data, and select the information matched in parenthesis 1, followed by a dash, the information matched in parenthesis 3, followed by a dash, then the the information matched in parenthesis 5.  You can do that function first, then check the length of the result, etc.

Comment: live example: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_E1F70JQKIKYEH3MNIPZPEOM9U.html

Comment: `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` could be simplified to `[0-9]{8}`.

Comment: Sure; just wanted to use same syntax as OP; I should have also listed the shortcut, which could also shorten the first part:  `[0-9][0-9]` could be `[0-9]{2}`

Comment: Thanks William for your suggestion.